# How to search on the basis of property Type in AEM

Tags: search, xpath, aem, query-builder

i want to search a property whose type is String[]. In my repository same property have both type 'String' & 'String[]' . i want to extract only those whose type is String[]. for this i'm using below query

```
path=/content/flip/us/usa/en_us/home/homepage
type=cq:PageContent
1_property=imageRotate
1_property.value=0
1_property.Type=string[]
```

But i getting result of String property also. Is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: IIUC, you want a way to restrict your search on properties of type string[] and exclude properties of type string. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes... your understanding is correct

Answer (score 2):

When you are searching for the multivalue properties you need to search with more than one value. as the type is same for both it only differs in the storage with multi valued.
Example to retrieve Multivalue property is as shown below

```
path=/content/geometrixx-outdoors
type=nt:unstructured
property.and=true
property=imageRotate
property.1_value=0
property.2_value=1
property.Type=string[]
```

[image: query builder]
[image: multivalueproperty]

XPathQuery :

```
/jcr:root/content/geometrixx-outdoors//element(*, nt:unstructured)
[
(@imageRotate = '0' and @imageRotate = '1') 
]
```